# Hot to initialize static const member in specialized template code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initialization, static-members

I'm currently not able to set up my class members like I want to. My templated class is only specialized for sensible integer types (unsigned and “small”). Each specialization needs a rather big look-up table that only depends on the type. So I thought it should definitely be static (and const) and created only once.

As C++ doesn't have static constructors I learned that you can create a class that does the heavy stuff on initialization and have that as a static member.

I reduced my code to these basics:

```
// Of this, I only want one instance per type,
// because the table can get big.
template<class T>
struct LookUp
{
    static int const SIZE = 1 << (sizeof(T) << 3);
    std::vector<T> table;

    LookUp()
        : table{ SIZE }
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            // Dummy code
            table[i] = i;
        }
    }
};

// "Normal" template class with common code for all types.
template<class T>
class LbpHelper
{
    typedef /*...*/ image;
};

// No functionality for the general case.
template<class T>
class Lbp
{
};

// But for this (among others) we have something.
template<>
class Lbp<uint8_t> : public LbpHelper<uint8_t>
{
    typedef uint8_t value_type;
    typedef Lbp::image image;

    static LookUp<value_type> _lookup; // <-- This is the mean one.

public:

    // Stuff...
};
```

Initializing static members seems to confuse a lot of users, especially when it comes to templates and specialization. I read quite some answers here but none of them solved my problem.

I tried having something like

```
// The type of the class is the same as the type of the member class.
template<> LookUp<uint8_t> Lbp<uint8_t>::_lookup{};
template<> LookUp<uint16_t> Lbp<uint16_t>::_lookup{};
```

in the *header* or the *source* file or *both*. I tried with or without a `class T` in the angle brackets (and using `T` to the right of course), leaving out the `template<>` alltogether, having the `{}`s only in the source — I don't know what else. Nothing worked.

Visual C++ either tells me that `_lookup` is **not a member** or that it is **not an entity that can be specialized** or this: **error C2373: '_lookup' : redefinition; different type modifiers**.

Can someone please tell me what to put where so that it compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the `template<>` bit, and put the definition of the static data members in a .cpp file:

```
LookUp<uint8_t> Lbp<uint8_t>::_lookup{};
LookUp<uint16_t> Lbp<uint16_t>::_lookup{};
```

[[Live example]](http://ideone.com/aKkCbg)

... and, since the type of `_lookup` is a class, you can leave out the `{}` as well; its default constructor will be called anyway. This might please VC++ if you're using a version which does not support uniform initialisation.

Why this is the proper way: `template<>` is used to introduce explicit specialisations. You're *not* introducing an explicit specialisation - you're defining a data member of an *already defined* explicit specialisation.

This is covered by C++11 14.7.3/5:

> ... Members of an explicitly specialized class template are
>   defined in the same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the `template<>` syntax. The same
>   is true when defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class. ...

Comment: Amazing, I'm 100% sure I tried this, but it didn't help. It seems I must have had another error which I cleared out during the preparation for this post. As they always say, “just explaining the problem to someone else might already bring new insights.”